# Previous "applications" missing in Zabbix 6 to be used by grafana

Tags: grafana, zabbix

Preparing the migration from a Zabbix 3.x / grafana environment to Zabbix 6.0 / grafana, I noticed I was unable to select a group in the "group" field (as not populated) within a dashboard.

[image]

Connectivity to Zabbix is fine ( according the built in test).

Reading documentation it seems previous "applications" in zabbix have become "tags". I however haven't found a comprehensive documentation on how to implement this.

Could someone assist or provide a hint as I'm at a loss right now.

Thx

Comment: groups are cached in grafana, more or less 1h interval between syncs. The Zabbix user need to have direct read permission to the group, or be a Superuser.

Comment: @IronBishop It's now several days.... Nothing in the list. This brings me to the "applications" missing in Zabbix 6.x

Comment: try writing something in the box, see if it triggers a completion after a few characters

Comment: maybe the first thing i tried.... using different browsers

Comment: Well It has to do with Zabbix permissions as when granting super admin it appears in he list. I'll need to go to ACL's fine tuning.